# Problems after importing obj human model

Tags: modeling, materials

I recalculated normals and removed doubles, but nothing works
Is the materials the reason?
Backface culling is enabled-1st screen, disabled -2nd screen

[image]

[image]

It is better now, but still... ( Set material to Shadeless and unchecked Transparency for each material)
[image]

Comment: In each material, under game settings, is backface culling enabled? under Options is there a value in z-offset? A script can fix every material if it is that.

Comment: Uncheck the Backface culling.

Comment: unchecked Backface, no result :( also there is no value in Z-offset

Comment: Are there some objects with x-ray enabled? What are your camera's clipping bounds?

Comment: Clipping bounds 0.1 - 20.000, played around with Z-offset of the materials - nothing happened. it is the only person so far, so- no xray